# Groovy method calling syntax

Tags: methods, groovy

I am quite new to groovy and getting following error when running the below method.

```
def hi() {
    println("Hello World!")
}

hi()

def runHi() {
    println("Running hi()")
    hi()
}

runHi()
```

It'll give:

```
===> true
Hello World!
===> null
===> true
Running hi()
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.hi() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I don't understand why `hi()` can run by itself but not within another method.

I've also tried:

```
static def hi() {
    println("Hello World!")
}

hi()

static def runHi() {
    println("Running hi()")
    hi()
}

runHi()
```

And that gives exact same error as well.

`No signature of method: static groovysh_evaluate.hi() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

What's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should run fine as a script. If you're running it through the Groovy Shell, you need to turn on interpreter mode:

> Shell variables are all untyped (i.e. no def or other type information).
> This will set a shell variable: `foo = "bar"`
> But, this will evaluate a local variable and will not be saved to the shell’s environment:
> `def foo = "bar"`
> This behavior can be changed by activating interpreter mode.

See http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html.